# How can I debug php gettext?

Tags: php, gettext

Some gettext keys aren't working for me - they show the key instead of the translation, though there is one. I'm making .mo file with PHP `File_Gettext` Pear library, and it seems to be working ok, so I've made the following script to try out, which keys aren't working fine:

```
$locale = 'en_GB';
$domain = 'messages';

setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
putenv("LC_ALL=".$locale);
bindtextdomain($domain, "D:/_gt");
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
textdomain($domain);

$mocreator = new File_Gettext_MO();
$mocreator->load('D:/_gt/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo');

foreach ($mocreator->strings as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == gettext($key)) {
        var_dump("ok");
    } else {
        var_dump($key, $value, gettext($key));
    }
}
```

From the output of the above I see that some keys work - I see a lot of `ok`s - and some don't, yielding the following:

```
string 'Cancelled' (length=9)
string 'Storniert' (length=9)
string 'Cancelled' (length=9)
```

So there is translation in the file, but gettext fails to use them for some reason.

Comment: Check the translation file. I think that gettext is more accurate than `File_Gettext_MO`. Look for the string `Cacnelled` therein, probably it's something you can see. You might want to add the part from your MO file to the question as well.

Comment: @hakre, I can see both `Cancelled` and `Storniert` in there. Which part of the file should I add?

Comment: What library is this? File_Gettext Pear? I can't find File_Gettext_MO anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now this is quite an old question, and I have have to point out that I'm not that well versed in gettext specific questions. But I've had some issues with array-keys as strings and encodings.

`D:/_gt` gives me the impression that you are using Windows of some kind, and if I'm not mistaken all Windows versions use latin-1-"with-special-locale" as default. I believe that the issue could be encoding related since you are specifying the file as *utf8* but I can't help you there without the *.mo* file. But try switching places of the `putenv` and the `setlocale` statements.

Or spaces missing? Could the correct key be `" Cancelled"`?

But as someone said in the comments, this is just guesswork without the *.mo* file.

If you already found your own answer, please add it to help the rest of the Internets! :D

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Windows issue, since there's the same script on the server with the same behavior. As you can see in the output, spaces are ok. Actually, I didn't find a solution for this - I'm just using DB + memcached now, which seems to work quite well.

Comment: Also, I tried to find some pattern in which the keys aren't working - like, multibyte character appears and all the subsequent keys are broken. But while the keys are alphabet ordered in the file, those which don't work are in random places.